# Why do some colors not return to original color after being made transparent

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

With my program, I am trying to create tiles of colors by only using the three primary colors, but I had been struggling with a problem setting the transparency for about a day now. It kept throwing a bad transparency mask even though I was setting the transparency of images correctly, I finally realized that the color yellow (after setting the transparency to 128 and then reverting it back to 255) actually does not retain its original color rather it just becomes black. I just want to know what is causing this problem, I have not been able to find anything about this in the Pillow library documentation. Here is my code for reference:

```
from PIL import Image

blue = Image.open('blue.png')
red = Image.open('red.png')
yellow = Image.open('yellow.png')

colors = [blue, red, yellow]

for main_color in colors:
    for color in colors:
        color_copy = main_color.copy()
        color.putalpha(128)

        color_copy.paste(im=color,box=(0,0),mask=color)
        new_colors.append(color_copy)

        color.putalpha(225)
```

I can't find the original image but by looking at the image properties it says that the size on the disk is 0 bytes

Comment: Not sure how anyone can run your code... you import no modules, neither open nor create any images and don't save anything.

Comment: Alright I have tried to make it as clear as possible

Comment: Please provide the 3 input images and an indication of what the desired output is. Thank you.